# Change string of object being called PHP

Tags: php

I have an object in this form:

```
{"q1":0,"q2":1,"q3":0,"q4":1,"q5":2,"q6":1,"q7":1,"q8":1,"q9":1,"q10":2,"q11":1,"q12":0,"q13":0,"q14":1,"q15":1,"q16":1,"q17":0,"q18":0,"q19":1,"q20":1,"q21":1,"q22":0,"q23":0,"qc1":[3,5,6,7],"qc2":[6],"qi1":"Good","qi2":"Bad","qi3":"Funny","qi4":"Hello"}
```

and I want to loop through each of the q's (so q1, q2, q3 etc.);

```
$tobeparsed = json_decode($result['surveyJSON']);
for($i=1; $i<23;$i++){
    $temp = "q".$i;
    $q[$i]=$tobeparsed->$temp;
}
```

This doesn't work because it has to be

```
$tobeparsed->q1;
```

but instead it is

```
$tobeparsed->"q1";
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use eval() http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: This is not what you need. Avoid eval like fire. Take a look at Andrew Answer Instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_decode` returns an StdObject.

If you want to get an array instead use this:

`json_decode($tobeparsed, true);`